# Php Кодировка

Tags: кодировка, php

Есть код php выводящий из бд идентификатор,имя,фамилию,должность.
Кодировка в мускуле id-нет; имя, фамилия, должность - utf-8;. 
 В самой странице php кодировка utf-8, Выводит в браузере id как нужно, а остальное иероглифы, меняю кодировку в броуере на utf-8( Стандартно в броузере почему то windows-1251), Всё нормально, но Id в иероглифах. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Пользуетесь ли вы какими-либо функциями для форматирования текста, прежде чем его выводить в браузер?

Comment: Сделал mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); После подключению к бд, помогло, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

то что в предыдущем ответе и в .htaccess добавьте строку

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

должно помочь

ну и из предыдущего ответа:
в файл html или php

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

при подключении БД

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Comment: html  

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

mysql

    SET character_set_results=utf8
    SET character_set_client=utf8
    SET character_set_connection=utf8
    SET character_set_results=utf8
    SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая фигня, что в html прописываешь `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`, а браузер все равно выводит в 1251, чтобы такого не происходило я из php дополнительно шлю хидер

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

он видимо имеет больший приоритет чем указание кодировки в разметке.

Ну и ID все таки должен им есть числовой формат.

И еще такая вещь, сама страница со скриптами тоже должна быть сохранена в utf-8

Comment: ну чтобы явно заголовок не слать можно и указать в .htaccess
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
и в заголовках всех страниц будет явно указываться кодировка